# LDAP UX screen flow for getting employees details

Tags: ux-designer, directory

I am going to design a screen flow for accessing LDAP server to get employee details in order to display in a page.  Initially I have designed one user flow where user can upload all employees' details in excel or csv and get them upload in server.  What we required to do here is, I want to manage the employees' details (Getting, inserting, deleting and updating) into LDAP server.  What is the UX best practice for designing UI screens to play with that.

If you have any samples or suggestions, would be really appreciated.

Provisions for screen flow has to be designed such a way user can contact with LDAP layer to interact with backend informations.  This is how I have been requested to design the screen flow. Honestly speaking, I am completely newbie for this domain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to deliver a usable system, you need to focus on the users' needs. What are their use cases? What tasks will these people need to accomplish? What information do they know coming in? How will they identify the people whose information they need to view or edit? How much info will they edit on average for each person? What is expected to be the most common use case?

Then, you can dig in to the details. You need to understand the data in order to most effectively present it: a Boolean flag might be indicated by a check mark, a short multiple choice answer might be radio buttons, while a longer might need a dropdown list. Some LDAP data are relationships between people and resources, your users may want you to offer navigation.  And some of the data may be sensitive and require special authorization to access (I can imagine an LDAP entry including a group membership in an executive compensation plan, for example, which might run afoul of the SOX act,) so be sure to ask your users to clarify the data, too.

When you've got a few of your users' most important use cases defined, mock up an interface that you think will meet their needs, and get their feedback. Listen to their complaints, and make improvements. Mock and test again.

You can't deliver a good UX until you know what the users need, and have tested it with them

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer.  Here is my reply for your answer.  I have list of fields including first name, last name, DOB kind of standard fields in my new application system.  Let's assume for enterprise level scenario.  Most of the large scale enterprises are already have their own user database which are having basic information as I mentioned above.  All I need to do is, import all user data into my application system rather than entering all details once again.  Here are my questions... Want to know how to configure LDAP server to my new system? and user flow to import user details.